# Binary tree layout removes duplicate branches

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees, tikz-graphs

What I want to do is draw a tree that doubles in size on each layer, so I thought a binary tree would be the right solution, as of right now I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    \title {
        Homework One\\
        \large COMP20180-Intro to Operating Systems}
    \author{}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle

    \section{}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
            \graph [binary tree layout] {
                4 -> {
                    3 -> {
                        2 -> {
                            1 -> {
                                0, 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The only problem is that tikz doesn't like drawing that last duplicated branch. The only workaround I've found is to change it to something else, which obviously doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

After some tests, it seems to me that a `graph` uses `node contents` as `node names`, therefore it's impossible that two nodes have the same contents because they are interpreted as the same node.

If you want to "write" the same contents into different nodes of a tree, you need to give a particular name to every node and use `as` option to assign the contents.

It's one of my first trials with `graphdrawing` so I could be wrong but this worked for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    \title {
        Homework One\\
        \large COMP20180-Intro to Operating Systems}
    \author{}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle

    \section{}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
            \graph [binary tree layout] {
                4 -> 3->2->1->{0,"0right"[as=0]}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]